# c# Json add new Value

Tags: c#, json, duplicates, append, addition

I need a C# Json add new value. Example:

The default json: http://pastebin.com/RTG6MD4Z

You know the line: 
`"authenticationDatabase": {
    "UUID": {
      "displayName": "name",
      "accessToken": "accessToken",
      "userid": "random",
      "uuid": "uuid",
      "username": "**Hidden**"
    }
  },`

Okey the authenticationDatabase: { add new value }

```
"authenticationDatabase": {
"UUID": {
  "displayName": "name",
  "accessToken": "accessToken",
  "userid": "random",
  "uuid": "uuid",
  "username": "**Hidden**"
},
"UUID": { // And the uuid not "UUID" random characters. (The new value)
   "displayName": "name",
   "accessToken": "accessToken",
   "userid": "random",
   "uuid": "uuid",
   "username": "**Hidden**"
},
"UUID": { // And the uuid not "UUID" random characters. (The new value)
   "displayName": "name",
   "accessToken": "accessToken",
   "userid": "random",
   "uuid": "uuid",
   "username": "**Hidden**"
}
```

},`

Comment: Your question makes no sense. You can't have 3 properties with the same name. Are you looking for an array?

Comment: What have you tried so far?  What JSON library are you using?  [tag:json.net], [tag:javascriptserializer] or something else?  The English of your question is unclear.  Can you create a [mcve] showing exactly what you want to do and where you need help in finishing?

Comment: I have a json.net dll code please? help me.

Answer (score 0):

You need to decide what you want to do:

```
"UUID": [{
  "displayName": "name",
  "accessToken": "accessToken",
  "userid": "random",
  "uuid": "uuid",
  "username": "**Hidden**"
},
{ // And the uuid not "UUID" random characters. (The new value)
   "displayName": "name",
   "accessToken": "accessToken",
   "userid": "random",
   "uuid": "uuid",
   "username": "**Hidden**"
},
{ // And the uuid not "UUID" random characters. (The new value)
   "displayName": "name",
   "accessToken": "accessToken",
   "userid": "random",
   "uuid": "uuid",
   "username": "**Hidden**"
}]
```

That is, use an array of objects, or decide you're not using JSON anymore and write your own parser and generator. But if you're passing this back and forth with somebody else you need to renegotiate your exchange format.